# Wordpress Admin Session Timeout - Recently Moved servers & URLs are set correctly

Tags: wordpress, apache, session, session-cookies

We moved our server and set the site up on AWS EC2 with an RDS database.

On the admin panel side, we continuously get the "session expired please login again" message almost every time we change pages. The URLs are set properly in the wp-config.php... The site is set to run entirely on HTTPS, not sure if that influences anything.

Server is Apache

Idk if there's server settings I need to fix or what? Really hoping for help fast...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to go to Settings > General and make sure the WordPress Address (URL) matches the Site Address (URL)?